# Conformal map from Mandelbrot set to Disk

Tags: fractals, conformal-geometry

Conformal maps from the complement of the Mandelbrot set to the disk are well known. Also, it is known that there exists a surjective conformal map from the interior of the Mandelbrot set to the disk by the Riemann mapping theorem.

Is an explicit example of a conformal map from the Mandelbrot set to the unit disk known?

Comment: Does the Riemann mapping theorem apply? Is the Mandelbrot set open? Is the interior of the Mandelbrot set simply connected?

Comment: @Claude Oh, good point. I forgot about the openness requirement.

Comment: @Claude You should be able to do it piecewise on the connected components of the interior, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the revised question suggested in the comment:

> you should be able to do it piecewise on the connected components of the interior

You can use the derivative of the limit cycle of points in hyperbolic components as a coordinate in the unit disc.  I believe the mapping is conformal, but I don't have a proof handy...

[image: interior coordinates]

Practically, you would check candidate periods $p$ where $|z_p|$ reaches a new minimum in iterations of $z_{n + 1} = f_c(z_n)$.  Use Newton's method to solve $z = f_c^p(z)$, using $z_p$ as initial guess.  If $\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial z} f_c^p(z)\right| \le 1$ (evaluated at the root you found), then $c$ is inside a hyperbolic component of period $p$, and $w = \frac{\partial}{\partial z} f_c^p(z)$ is mapped to the unit disc.  I have no proof of correctness of this algorithm, but it seems to work...

Comment: This is fantastic!  Can I see your code?

Comment: @MikeStay https://code.mathr.co.uk/mandelbrot-graphics/blob/5a077c0f0f38612f5770cedc270ba28904b74674:/c/lib/m_d_compute.c https://code.mathr.co.uk/mandelbrot-numerics/blob/2531b0d8cf81d21293a1d32b0d62a9b25f3c1bf0:/c/lib/m_d_interior_de.c are the best places to start I guess, no comments unfortunately... Haskell version linked from my blog post https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2013-04-01_interior_coordinates_in_the_mandelbrot_set.html